# How to use MediatorLiveData with an abstract source

Tags: android, kotlin, abstract-class, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

I have an abstract class, with a `MediatorLiveData` object in it. This object has a number of sources, one of which depends on the childs class, and is `abstract` in the parent class.
Adding the sources in an `init` block causes a NullPointerException at runtime, because at the time the init block adds the source, it is still abstract (or so I have been led to believe).

Is there a way to use an `abstract` `LiveData` as a source for a `MediatorLiveData` without having to set that source in a child class? I just want to `override val` and be done with it, since I definitely will forget to call the `addSources()` function at some time in the future.

(I am aware that this example is not the most useful way to do this exact thing, but I didn't want to add unneccesary complexity)

Example:

```
abstract class MyClass: ViewModel(){
    private val _myMediator = MediatorLiveData<String>()
    
    protected abstract val mySource: LiveData<String>
    
    val myObservable: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myMediator
    
    // This will cause a NullPointerException at runtime
    init{
        _myMediator.addSource(mySource){ _myMediator.value = it }
    }
    
    //This should work, but requires this to be called in child class
    protected fun addSources(){
        _myMediator.addSource(mySource){ _myMediator.value = it }
    }
}

class myChild: MyClass(){
    override val mySource = Transformations.map(myRepository.someData) { it.toString() }
    
    // This is where init { addSources() } would be called
}
```

After reading Stachu's anwser, I decided to go with this, which I didn't test butI think should work:

```
abstract class MyFixedClass: ViewModel(){
    private val _myMediator: MediatorLiveData<String> by lazy{
        MediatorLiveData<String>().apply{
            addSource(mySource){ this.value = it }
        }
    }

    protected abstract val mySource: LiveData<String>

    val myObservable: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myMediator
}

class MyChild: MyFixedClass(){
    override val mySource = Transformations.map(myRepository.someData) { it.toString() }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using lazy evaluation, e.g. something like this

```
abstract class MyClass : ViewModel() {
    private val _myMediator = MediatorLiveData<String>()
    private val _mySource: LiveData<String> by lazy { mySource() }
    protected abstract fun mySource(): LiveData<String>
    val myObservable: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myMediator
    init {
        _myMediator.addSource(_mySource) { _myMediator.value = it }
    }
}

class myChild : MyClass() {
    override fun mySource() = Transformations.map(myRepository.someData) { it.toString() }
}
```

Comment: Ended up making the MediatorLiveData lazy since I think in your example `mySource()` might get called before being overridden. Will put it in the question. Thanks!